# problems launching roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch

Tags: ros, jetson

When launching `roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch`, I got the following error:

```
process[rviz-1]: started with pid [12021]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [hector_mapping/hector_mapping]: Cannot locate node of type [hector_mapping] in package [hector_mapping]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable (chmod +x)
process[base_to_laser_broadcaster-3]: started with pid [12022]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [hector_trajectory_server/hector_trajectory_server]: Cannot locate node of type [hector_trajectory_server] in package [hector_trajectory_server]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable (chmod +x)
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [hector_geotiff/geotiff_node]: Cannot locate node of type [geotiff_node] in package [hector_geotiff]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable (chmod +x)
```

Comment: [This ROSAnswers post](https://answers.ros.org/question/391610/error-when-running-hector-slam-tutoriallaunch-file/) seems related to the same issue. If you are using ROS Noetic, you could try `sudo apt install ros-noetic-hector-mapping`, then source and launch again, as suggested at the provided link.